# MYSQL is not starting on xampp

Tags: php

```
Error:MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums.
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: are you using xamp

Comment: try to stop skype

Comment: Please provide more data, like what are you trying to run in xampp and maybe few relevant lines from the error logs (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem recently.

If you have `SQL Server Management Studio` installed, try stopping the service:

```
SQL Server Reporting Services
```

I understand that there are myriad reasons you could be experiencing this; this was my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `Skype` has your `xampp` port taken. Try ending the skype or any other application taking that port from your task manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change port, maybe another application (skype) took it. Or just try to reinstall your xampp package. It almost always works.